# OpenEthereum Freezer (move ancient data to HDD)?

Tags: openethereum

Go Ethereum 1.9 [has a nice feature](https://blog.ethereum.org/2019/07/10/geth-v1-9-0/) to move ancient data "to the freezer". Does OpenEthereum provide the same feature?